# how to code to stop/pause zune music in windowsphone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-process, zune

Does anyone knows, how to code in c# to stop/pause the zune music in windowsphone7. I used background music in my application, if i launch my application, zune music stops. how to handle this? i use windowsphone7 version, so cant able to use BackgroundAudioPlayer instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't stop the users background music if it's already playing and you're not going to play music yourself.

If you wish to play music in your app then (after confirming with the user that it's ok to stop the currently plaing music) just start playing your music and this will then cause the music that was playing to be stopped.

There is no way to automatically resume the musc that was playing prevviously when you stop playing your music.